# Terraform: how to create resource from loop through a objects with inner list

Tags: list, loops, object, terraform, aws-glue

I am working with Terraform and I need to create a Glue Workflow. My target is the following schema:
[image]

I don't understand how I can use the "nested loops" to create the  resouce from a variable object with a list of string:

My main.tf file is:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "<MY-STAGE>" 
}

locals {
    workflow_name = "my_example"
    first_job = "Job_start"
    my_map = [
        {
            flow = ["JOB-A1", "JOB-A2", "JOB-A3"]
        },
        {
            flow = ["JOB-B1", "JOB-B2", "JOB-B3"]
        }
    ]
}

resource "aws_glue_workflow" "example" {
  name = "example"
} 

resource "aws_glue_trigger" "example-start" {
  name          = "trigger-start"
  type          = "ON_DEMAND"
  workflow_name = local.workflow_name
  actions {
    job_name = "${replace(lower(local.first_job), "_", "-")}"
  }
}

resource "aws_glue_trigger" "this" {
  for_each = toset(local.my_map) 
  name          = "trigger-inner--${lower(element(each.key, index(local.my_map, each.key)))}"
  type          = "CONDITIONAL"
  workflow_name = aws_glue_workflow.example.name
  predicate {
    conditions {
    job_name = "${replace(lower(element(each.key, index(local.my_map, each.key))), "_", "-")}"
      state    = "SUCCEEDED"
    }
  }
  actions {
    job_name = "${replace(lower(element(each.key, index(local.my_map, each.key) + 1)), "_", "-")}"
  }
}
```

When I try to do the "plan" I get this error:

```
| each.key is a string, known only after apply
| local.my_map is tuple with 2 elements
| Call to function "element" failed: cannot read elements from string.
```

Then, how can I get all the rows of the object and scroll through the list elements?
Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: The `job_name` is only for one job? So you would have to have sequences of three jobs?

Comment: I would start from one "job" and to have N  sequences of flows parallel of  N jobs. The number of parallel flow depends from the rows of "my_map" and the number of Jobs depends from the number of items into the lists.

Comment: But the `job_name` is only a single value? Just asking because I'm not sure how it works. I did make the plan work locally, but not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: The job_name is the name of a job to be executed. 
Then yes,  is a single value: "JOB-A1" then "JOB-A2" and so on.

Comment: And that switch between the jobs should happen in a single Glue trigger resource? Or for example the `job_name` in the `predicate` should be "JOB-A1" and the `job_name` in `actions` should be "JOB-A2"?

Comment: Lo switch of the job should happen in the predicate and in the action as you have described. 
For every passage the trigger action value is JOB-A2 and the predicate value is JOB-A1, and the chain go on 

(1 -  predicate: JOB-A1 , action JOB-A2), 
(2 - predicate: JOB-A2 , action JOB-A3),
(...),
(N -  predicate: JOB-A(N-1) , action JOB-AN),

This becose "predicate" specify when the new trigger should fire and the "action" are actions initiated by this trigger when it fires.

Comment: Ah, ok, I might have an idea then